# File paths when using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filepath, fs

So I know that the `fs` module uses `process.cwd()` and not the actual location of the module but I'm still having a little issue with file paths.

So I've a app structure like this:

```
- app
   - controllers
   - models
   - views
   - tmp
   - index.js
```

I'm creating csv files in a controller, and hope to store it in `tmp`.

So considering that despite being in controllers,

```
process.cwd() is '/app'
```

I did this:

```
fs.open('tmp/FILENAME','w',function (err,fd) {
```

err is null so that seems to work fine. So that should be in /app/tmp/

On the other hand, in index.js I have

```
res.attachment(__dirname + '/tmp/FILENAME')
```

which when console.logged is

```
/app/tmp/FILENAME
```

which is correct. So clearly the other half is causing the problem.

So my question is - **What is the correct way to use fs in this scenario, taking into consideration process.cwd() ?**
Kinda stumped, any ideas?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are asking, can you rephrase so your problem is clear?

Answer (score 1):

relying on `process.cwd()` is risky, some other piece of code you introduce later on could change it.

using `__dirname + '/tmp/FILENAME'` is safer.

Comment: so, how do I utilise `__dirname` to get a directory that is in effect a sibling to the one I'm in?

Comment: __dirname + "../" + sibling_name